# youtube-data-api, unable to get channel list using username

Tags: youtube-data-api

i want to list all channel of a particular user, from youtube using youtube data api. For example: there are 9 channels in user "MyCupcakeaddiction" so i want to list all channels.
Please help

Comment: Show what you have so far. We're here to help, not to write code for you. Also, you should add a tag for whatever programming language you're using. As soon as this question slips of the front page, only people searching for `youtube-data-api-v3` are likely to see this. Seeing as there's only 144 questions with this tag, that's also quite unlikely.

Comment: i have tried this api "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet,contentDetails&forUsername=MyCupcakeaddiction&key={mykey}&maxResults25"  but it returns only single result.